# How to find out if the current time of HH:MM is in two intervals HH:MM - HH:MM

Tags: php, mysql

There are two dates in the database, opening date (HH:MM) and closing date (HH:MM), for example 07:00 (open) - 20:00 (closed) or 07:00 - 03:00

It is necessary that the date is correctly determined in such periods:

Example:

There is an institution that opens at 07:00 and closes at 23:00, and now 20:00, how do you know if this institution is open now?

Or open at 07:00 and closes at 03:00 (the next day), and now 20:00

Or open at 22:00 and closes at 07:00 (the next day), now 02:00

Or open at 22:00 and closes at 07:00 (the next day), now 23:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two cases:

Case one: `opening_time < closing_time` (opened over the day)

Case two: `opening_time > closing_time` (opened over the night)

For the two cases you need diffrent conditions.

For case one:

```sql
current_time() > opening_time AND current_time() < closing_time
```

For case two:

```sql
current_time() > opening_time OR current_time() < closing_time
```

Now combine the cases with their corresponding conditions into a single statement:

```sql
(opening_time < closing_time) AND (current_time() > opening_time AND current_time() < closing_time)
OR
(opening_time > closing_time) AND (current_time() > opening_time OR  current_time() < closing_time)
```

Since the first condition is now rdundant, you can remove it. Your final query would be:

```sql
SELECT 
    (current_time() > opening_time AND current_time() < closing_time)
    OR
    (opening_time > closing_time) AND (current_time() > opening_time OR current_time() < closing_time)
    AS is_open_now
FROM your_table
-- your WHERE condition here
```

This is pure boolean logic. But another way to deal with different cases is to use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN opening_time < closing_time
    THEN current_time() > opening_time AND current_time() < closing_time
    ELSE current_time() > opening_time OR  current_time() < closing_time
  END AS is_open_now
FROM your_table
-- your WHERE condition here
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, this is not exactly specified in the question. I would argue, that it should be `>= opening_time` and `< closing_time`. Or is a shop still opened at 20:00 when it closes at 20:00?

Answer (score 2):

check this query. @now is only for testing. you must change it later to NOW()

here a [sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4960e/20)

```
SELECT @now := '14:00:01';

SELECT *,
  if( open_time < close_time
     , if( @now >= open_time and @now <= close_time , 'in period' , 'out period')
     , if( @now >= open_time or @now <= close_time , 'in period' , 'out period'))
as period
FROM docs;
```

Comment: I'm afraid, the second condition isn't correct. Assuming we are open from 20:00 to 03:00. `@now <= open_time` will be TRUE for `18:00 <= 20:00` - But we are closed at 18:00. You need to reverse `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: Yes. Can you correct it. I am out and habe only my mobile

Comment: @Paul Spiegel - Thanks for helping to Paul